# Set local name for Bluetooth LE advertisement

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-peripheral

I'm working on Android Bluetooth LE peripheral (advertisement). I can change the advertisement name with below snippet code:

```
BluetoothAdapter.setName(name);
...
AdvertiseData.setIncludeDeviceName(true)
```

But, this also changes the Devise's Bluetooth name, that I wont. 
I know that in iOS it's possible to set a local name for advertisement without effecting on Device's Bluetooth name.

How can achieve this in Android?

Comment: hi you got solution?

Comment: @Vijaykumar, Unfortunately no, and I think that is not possible.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply.